# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline supply GitHub SSH credentials for a 'sh' build step

Tags: git, jenkins, github, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `sh` step in a scripted Jenkins pipeline that in turn asks git to clone a private GitHub repository via SSH (it's a dependency management system that handles a dependency hosted on GitHub). The pipeline itself is executed via the GitHub Organisation Plugin. It includes a `checkout scm` command that also accesses a private repository, from the log I see that it makes use of the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to pass the login-information to that step (that works fine). Is there a way to pass that same information also to another step, i.e. my `sh "install_dependencies.sh"` step? Note that `withCredentials` would give me access to the credentials via environment variables, but how do I pass them to git? `GIT_SSH` is the path to a ssh wrapper script, which I do not know how to generate with `withCredentials`. Is there another way to pass credentials to git via environment variables?

A minimal `Jenkinsfile` would look as follows:

```
node {
    checkout scm  // successfully accesses github credentials
    withCredentials([
        // what to put here?
    ]) {
        // install python dependencies
        sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
    }
    sh 'pytest'
}
```

The file `requirements.txt` lists dependencies, it contains a line of the form

`-e git+ssh://git@github.com/some_private/repo@dev#egg=egg_name`

which instructs to `pip` to fetch the requirement via `git`.

It is probably possible to manually check-out the code using another Jenkins `checkout scm` step and then install it from within the Jenkinsfile. However, that would defeat the purpose of having `requirements.txt` as the single source of truth for requirements.

Comment: Are you saying your `requirements.txt` has dependencies being pulled in by `git`? I did not know `pip` could do that.

Comment: It does: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the question and what worked for me according to the docs was

```
        withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'Credential-id', keyFileVariable: 'CERT')]) {
      sh 'cp -prf $CERT ~/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
}
```

this copies the certificate from the location it is to the local docker certificate store.
which than allows me to clone while doing dependency pulling